# Does Sarkhan the Dragonspeaker tap with his +1?

Tags: magic-the-gathering

A friend and I had a little confusion. He was playing with [Sarkhan, the Dragonspeaker](https://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?name=Sarkhan%2C%20the%20Dragonspeaker) and activated the +1, then attacked. The creature did not have vigilance, and wasn't destroyed. So naturally, it would tap. But my friend said because it goes back to being a planeswalker at the end of the turn, it doesn't tap.

So, is there any rule that clarifies this?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes, you'll tap him to attack, like any other creature. The same goes for any other planeswalker that's presently a creature (unless it has vigilance, as you've noticed), such as [Gideon Jura](https://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?name=Gideon%20Jura) — being creatures, they'll follow any of the usual rules for creatures.

This also means that when he returns to being a plain old planeswalker, he'll be tapped. Planeswalkers can be tapped! There's nothing saying planeswalkers can't be tapped. He'll untap at your next untap step, just like any other permanent.

Comment: Great appreciation, Doppelgreener. That is what I thought would happen.

Answer (score 1):

Any permanent can be tapped, although planeswalkers and enchantments are rarely tapped. "Tappedness" is a property of all permanents. Doppelgreener's answer explains the situation well, but here are the supporting rules:

From the comprehensive rules:

> **110.6**. A permanent’s status is its physical state. There are four status categories, each of which has two possible values: tapped/untapped, flipped/unflipped, face up/face down, and phased in/phased out. Each permanent always has one of these values for each of these categories.

On untapping:

> **502.2**. Second, the active player determines which permanents he or she controls will untap. Then he or she untaps them all simultaneously. This turn-based action doesn’t use the stack. Normally, all of a player’s permanents untap, but effects can keep one or more of a player’s permanents from untapping.